# Converting an LDIF into WebSEAL Group Import -- " not printing properly

Tags: regex, perl

I took an LDIF and went through it line by line putting the DN into a variable $line and then matching out the cn into a variable $cn.

Now I simply want to print out all the lines like this:

group import CNHERE "DN HERE"

I should get one statement per each DN in the LDIF.  Instead any time I try to get it to print the " " around the $line variable I get the funky output below.

```
"roup import CNNAMEHERE "dn: CN=CNNAMEHERE,OU=Groups,DC=extranet,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
```

Here is a sample DN line from the file.

```
dn: CN=CNNAMEHERE,OU=GROUPNAME,OU=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
```

I know I could just print it out with a different character then find/replace the file or do a substitution match but I'd really like to know why it's doing this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (DATA, "<exportGroupsEmpty.ldf") or die ("Couldn't open file");

my $line = "";

while($line = <DATA>)
{

  #get DN
  if ($line =~ m/^dn/)
  {

    my $cn = "";
    $line =~ m/(dn: CN=)/;
    $' =~ m/(,)/;
    $cn = $`;
    chomp($line);

    print qq(group import $cn "$line"\n);
    #print $cn;
    #print " " . $line . "\n";

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to dos2unix the input file.